# Set a delay between each i = i + 1

Tags: javascript

I have a `for` loop that creates an array of the numbers 1-40. When the user holds down the up or down key, the numbers increase or decrease via `i++` and `i—-`.

For some reason, this works great and each number changes at a steady pace- but it’s a bit faster than I would like, and I cannot figure out how to manipulate it.

Is there a JavaScript method to make `i = i + 1`, stop for a few milliseconds, and then repeat through each iteration?

Comment: please add the code as well.

Comment: did you try using `setTimeout(() => {i = i+1;}, time);` time in milliseconds (2000 = 2s)

Comment: Well, since you have no code I will just comment - write a function to do the incrementing and call it with SetInterval or SetTimeout (see which is more appropriate for your case). That should work.

Comment: @NinaScholz I’m trying to figure out how to add my code. It’s actually a lot more complicated than what I posted because it’s a game made with Phaser. Basically I have a sprite that incrementally follows the position of an array of other sprites.

Comment: @Kardon63 yes, when I try that with 5000 milliseconds, the program waits for 5 seconds and then behaves as it normally would. I need it to increment by one, wait 5 seconds, increment by one again, wait 5 seconds, etc.

Comment: okk then use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeOut`

Answer (score 1):

```js
function delay(ms) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))}

(async ()=>{

   for(var i=0;i<40;i++){
       await delay(2000)
   }

})()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, you can write something like:

```
function wait() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
  resolve();
}, 1000); // lets say wait one second
});
}
```

Then on click function you can call:

```
async buttonClick = () = {
   await wait();
   // increase value and do stuff
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check save press time to global variable like `pressTime = new Date();` and check difference with current time as `new Date() - pressTime` it will return difference in `milliseconds` so use your desired time interval. If it is larger then your expected time then update value and `pressTime` also.

Try it below.

```js
document.getElementById('input').onkeydown = keydown;

let i = 0;
let pressTime = new Date();

function keydown(e) {
  if ((e.keyCode == '38' || e.keyCode == '40') && new Date() - pressTime > 1000) {
    e.keyCode == '38' ? i++ : i--;
    pressTime = new Date();
    document.getElementById('input').value = i;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id='input' type='text' value='0' />
```